# length of secant line.

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm looking for way to find the length of a secant line intersecting another line through the center of a circle with a known radius. The intersection point is on the circle and the angle between 2 lines is also known.
Attached image should clarify:

```
p is the intersection point of the two lines pd and pe on the circle.
pe is the line through the center and is 2 x radius (known).
a is the angle (known).
```

I would like to know an easy way to find the length of pd, and ideally also the length of pf intersecting with the tangent of circle parallel to pe.

I found the intersecting secants theorem, but this is of no use as the intersection point is outside the circle.

[image]

Comment: For $pf$, note that $\frac{pf}{r}=\sin  a$. Here $r$ is the radius of the circle.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry for steal your idea to complement my answer

Comment: No problem! It is useful for the answer to be complete. And pictures are a very good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The triangle PED having one side on the diameter of the circle is a right triangle.

If the angle of DPE is $\alpha$  some trigonometry tolds you:

$$\cos{\alpha}=\frac{PD}{2r}$$
$$PD=2r\cos{\alpha}$$

For $PF$ as André Nicolas stated you can see this:

[image]

The lenght of FG is equal to the radius (because the line tangent is parallel to  the diameter, therefore some trigonometry again gives:

$$\sin{\alpha}=\frac{r}{PF}$$ 
$$PF=\frac{r}{\sin{\alpha}}$$

Comment: for $DF$, use this, the comment of André, and the fact that $PF-PD=DF$.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that PD And DE are perpendicular, I'm almost sure this has been proved to me during math classes. (I should refresh my memory). With PED being a 90 degrees corner the problem is quite solvable indeed.